# Does anyone have test data that illustrates the CryptoNight 7 algorithm?

Tags: cryptonight, algorithm, difficulty-algorithm, blockchain-data

With the new CryptoNight 7 algorithm Monero introduced back in April, does anyone have an example of a data blob and a nonce that successfully hashes the block?  I'm trying to figure out how to test their algorithm and I'd like some valid data to verify that the algorithm I'm using is correct.

This is basically a rehash of this quesiton -- [Where can I find some test inputs and outputs for the CryptoNight (Monero PoW) hash algorithm?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6998/where-can-i-find-some-test-inputs-and-outputs-for-the-cryptonight-monero-pow-h), except I'm looking for CryptoNight 7 instead of just CryptoNight.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to call the [daemon RPC](https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#getblock)'s method `getblock`. From this you can get the `result.blob` (the data to be hashed) and from the `result.block_header.hash`, the expected hash result.